# Barra de estatus de envió de paquetes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Mi pregunta seria si tienen algun sitio de donde pueda obtener una barra y como utilizarla, parecida a la de los envios de paquetes.

|---preparando paquete----------------|enviado|-------------|entregado|----|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

he encontrado un plugin de angular que te vendrá genial: https://github.com/angular-wizard/angular-wizard.

Tendrás que importarlo:

```
angular.module('your-app', ['mgo-angular-wizard']);
```

Y aquí te dejo un ejemplo de uso:

```
<wizard on-finish="finishedWizard()" on-cancel="cancelledWizard()"> 
    <wz-step wz-title="Starting">
        <h1>This is the first step</h1>
        <p>Here you can use whatever you want. You can use other directives, binding, etc.</p>
        <input type="submit" wz-next value="Continue" />
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step wz-title="Continuing">
        <h1>Continuing</h1>
        <p>You have continued here!</p>
        <input type="submit" wz-next value="Go on" />
    </wz-step>
    <wz-step wz-title="More steps">
        <p>Even more steps!!</p>
        <input type="submit" wz-next value="Finish now" />
    </wz-step>
</wizard>
```

En el enlace también tiene toda la documentación.

Comment: Bien! Justo lo que queria,gracias!